# Where spfun meets bsxfun

Tags: matlab

Is there way to perform element-wise operations like `bsxfun` does, but *only* operate on the non-zero elements of a sparse matrix?

In particular, for each non-zero element in matrix `A` at position `(i,j)` I want to find the product of all of the non-zero elements in the `i`-th row, except for element `(i,j)`.

For example if the `i-th` row looks like this:

```
0   5   3   0   0   4   0  0
```

The result should look like this:

```
0   12  20  0   0   15  0  0
```

The most obvious solution seem to be to take the product of the non-zero elements along each row, and then divide each element back out of the row product.  So, in the above example, the row product is `5 x 3 x 4 = 60`, and then I just divide out `5` `3` and `4` at their respective locations.

Given a sparse matrix `A`, this is my best solution so far:

```
[M N] = size(A);
[row col vals] = find(A);
row_prod = accumarray(row,vals,[],@prod);
B = bsxfun(@ldivide, A, row_prod);
B = sparse(row,col,B(sub2ind([M N],row,col)),M,N);
```

The first three lines achieve what I want: a column vector representing the product of the non-zero elements of each row.  However, there are quite a few problems with the last two lines.

`bsxfun` is going to return a non-sparse matrix the size of `A`

It is going to waste a LOT of cycles dividing by zero unnecessarily.

The result is a matrix comprised mostly of `Inf` or `-Inf` where I really just want zeros.

I can't mask out the `Inf`s because Matlab defines zero times infinity to be `NaN`.

Do I just need to bite the bullet and write a for-loop for this?  Or is there another way to approach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found a solution that resolves most of my concerns above.  Sometimes when I have the `bsxfun` hammer in my hand, the whole world starts to look like a nail.  I forget that some of the simple multiplications that I do with `bsxfun` could be just as easily (and arguably more readably) solved using matrix multiplication.  While I don't think that my solution to this problem is any more readable, it is orders of magnitude more efficient than my last solution.

```
% 'This happens once, outside the loop, since the size'
% 'and sparsity structure of A dont change in the loop'
[M N] = size(A);
[row col] = find(A);

%% 'Inside iterative loop'

    % 'Get the product of non-zero row elements'
    row_prod = accumarray(row,nonzeros(A),[],@prod);

    % 'Use row products to compute 'leave-one-out' row products'
    B = spdiags(row_prod,0,M,M)*spfun(@(x) 1./x, A);
```

I would still be interested in hearing other suggestions if this can be improved.